# How to recover a failed jsonrequest from a requestqueue

Tags: android-volley, jsonresponse

I'm working on a volley POST call from an Android java app that will work onboard a ship where communications are not very good, so there are many fails.
The data are sent every 5 minutes to a requestqueue that can accumulate many requests, some of them will fail.
I pretend to configure the jsonObjectRequest to insert the failed data into a local database to be synchronize again when ship arrives on port.
My question is if there is a way to configure jsonObjectRequest for obtain failed jsonrequest to be executed when an error response is received or when requestqueue produces a timeout?

My code

```
    public void sincronizar_servidor_fast() {
        String postUrl = "";
        JSONObject json_to_add=new JSONObject();
        try{
            json_to_add.put("datos",datos_array);
            System.out.println("json_to_add");
             }catch (JSONException e){}
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl, json_to_add, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();   
            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(180),               -1,            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            if (register_ddbb1) {
                if (db != null) {
                    db.execSQL("");
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for the amendment